# Bad Request Error uploading file to the server

Tags: php, upload

I have a dedicated server and am having problems with uploading files larger than 3mb and sometimes even lower.

I get this message:

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request this server que Could Not understand.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Very sought the solution to this problem but can not find the settings for max upload size max, limit has changed to higher values ​​but without success.

What can be happening?

My form:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Arquivo: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My PHP:

```
$pasta    = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/app/upload/imagens/";
$tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$name     = $pasta.$_FILES["file"]["name"];
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $name)) {

} else {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["error"];
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see some code that you're using to handle the upload request.

Comment: Check your forms method is POST, will need to see your code though

Comment: I put the codes above

Answer (score 0):

This may be a cookie problem. Either clear your cache and delete your cookies, or go into the cookies folder and delete the cookies for that site manually.

And for second part (*Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request*) The **ErrorDocument** directive, when supplied a local URL path, expects the path to be fully qualified from the DocumentRoot

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve. The problem presented in the logs was: ModSecurity: Access denied with code 400 (phase 2). Match of "eq 0" against "MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY" [msg "Multipart parser detected a possible unmatched boundary."]

So I edited the file: modsec2.conf and everything worked fine.

Thanks to friends.